# How to make connection between id and a string?

Tags: php

I use php and mysql, I'll try to make it simple, instead to place all my code.

I have an ID for example ID=106

And I have this list of strings, after _ is the same number as ID

```
BE1064490_101
BE1064501_102
BE1064512_103
BE1064523_104
BE1064534_105
BE1064545_106
BE1064556_107
BE1064567_108
BE1064578_109
BE1064589_110
```

So my mission is, when ID is equal to, lets say, 106 to echo(show) BE1064545_106

So, I actually am looking for ideas where I shoud start?
this list must be like an array? or not?

```
$array = array(
    "BE1064490_101" => "101",
    "BE1064501_102" => "102",
);
```

PS: I know how to explode

```
explode('_', $code);
```

I have updated the array

```
    $array = array(
"BE1064490" => "101",
"BE1064501" => "102",
"BE1064512" => "103",
"BE1064523" => "104",
"BE1064534" => "105",
"BE1064545" => "106",
}
```

I use

```
if (in_array($userid, $array)) {
    echo key($array).'_'.$userid;
}
```

Now it searches the ID in the aray but doesnt give me back its KEY, so I only get the first KEY. No matter what is the Id value.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can use an array as a dictionary, but you should use the ID as key, the string as value. Or you use the database to store data, much more efficient for bugger and dynamic data sets.

Comment: Yeah, but the key should be the id....so you then can simple look at the id in the array, like: `$array[theId]`

Comment: oh, i think no need to use database cince there will be only certain amount of those cods

Comment: Where are you getting these codes, or are you hand typing them?

Comment: you need hashmaps, in php arrays are hashmaps, just use number as key and string as value (ie swap id and string)

Comment: Did you give up or what?

Answer (score 0):

try this if the id always contain the same amount of characters.

```
<?php $a = 'BE1064545_106'; if(substr($a, 10,3)=='106'){ echo $a;} else echo "something else";?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip your array and it should be easy:

```
$array = array (
  101 => 'BE1064490',
  102 => 'BE1064501',
  103 => 'BE1064512',
  104 => 'BE1064523',
  105 => 'BE1064534',
  106 => 'BE1064545',
);

$id = 102;
echo $array[$id];  // BE1064501
```

You may want to check first:

```
if(isset($array[$id])) {
    echo $array[$id];  // BE1064501
} else {
    echo "$id not found";
}
```